# comparing two discrete distributions

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I have set A of passwords created under policy A and set B of passwords created under policy B. Maximum password length in both conditions is 15. The number of passwords in each set is nearly 70.

I found that 50% passwords in set A are of length 8 and no password in set A has length 11 and 13.

While in set B passwords length vary from 8 to 15. The proportion of passwords in set B having length 8 to 15 doesn't seem to vary much.

Clearly the password length created with policy B is relatively unpredictable.

How do I capture this intuition more formally. Is there any statistical measure to do so? I have the password length distribution for set A as well as set B.

Performing Chi square test of independence with null hypothesis "passwords created under policy A and policy B has no effect on the resulting password length" will reject the null hypothesis. Am I right?

Also if the policies has effect on password length, policy B seems to create more secure passwords, since in this case the proportion of passwords belonging to different lengths are somewhat similar. How do I capture this intuition?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do two things:

1. *Represent the fact that policy B results in longer passwords.* For this I would just give the mean of each policy's password length distribution. To show the difference is statistically significant you could use a t-test, provided you have a reasonably large sample set of passwords from both policies.
2. *Quantify the added "unpredictability" that policy B has, given that its password length distribution is flat, while policy A has a spike at length 8 passwords.* For this you should calculate the [information entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) of each length distribution. The expected result is that B has higher entropy. The difference Entropy(B)-Entropy(A) will quantify the number of "extra bits of information" that a password cracker must guess under policy B, relative to policy A.

Comment: why not chi squared or Fischer Exact test to show the statistical significance?

Comment: I have 2 policies and 8 different lengths (from 8 to 15). So can't I treat this as a contingency table of 2X8 (2 policies and 8 different lengths)?

Comment: You can do that, but all it will do is show that the password length distributions under policies A and B are different. The t test and the entropy are more informative about the differences that have security relevance.